# To open Project Properties WIndow (Java Build Path) automatically using code

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, buildpath

I am developing an Eclipse plugin which would create a new Java project and few classes inside it.
Once the plugin wizard closes (after I click finish in the final page), i need the Project Properties window of this particular project to be opened automatically.

I must achieve that through code, any examples please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the final answer. This is how it goes:

```
Shell shell = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell();
MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Project Proeperties", "Properties window will open next");

String propertyPageId = "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.propertyPages.BuildPathsPropertyPage";
PreferenceDialog dialog = PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn(shell, iProject, propertyPageId, null, null);
    dialog.open();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil`

```
PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn(shell, element, null, null, null).open();
```

will display the full `Properties` dialog. The parameters allow you to choose the initial page and filter the pages shown.

The `element` parameter would be the `IProject` for the project.

You can find existing property page ids using the Eclipse `Search` dialog. Select the `Plug-in Search` tab and enter the property page extension point id `org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages` in the `Search string`. Set `Search For` to `Extension Point`, set `Limit To` to `References` and `Scope` to `Workspace`. 
[image: Search dialog]

Perform the search to get the plug-ins which use this extension point. Opening a search result will open the plugin.xml for the plugin at the extension point.

Comment: do you have any idea of how to get this **propertyPageId** please. For example, to open the _Run/Debug settings under Project Properties_, we define `String propertyPageId = "org.eclipse.debug.ui.properties.defaultLaunchConfigurations";` Likewise what must be the propertyPageId value to open the _BuildPath_ settings. I tried to find out, but couldnt. Thanks

Comment: Once I get this propertyPageId, as greg says, my code would go like, `PreferenceDialog dialog = PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn(shell, project, propertyPageId, null, null); return dialog.open();` Waiting for the answer friends.

Comment: Java Build Paths property page is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.propertyPages.BuildPathsPropertyPage`